# SQL SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE id IN (SELECT ids FROM tableB WHERE 1)

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I'm looking for the result of this query:

```
SELECT * FROM procesos WHERE estatus=1 AND id_proceso IN (3,1,5,7,4,6,8)
```

[image]

But selecting the processes from the following query:

```
SELECT procesos FROM tipos_fichas WHERE id_tipo='1'
```

[image]

What I have tried without success is this:

```
SELECT * FROM procesos WHERE estatus=1 AND id_proceso IN (SELECT procesos FROM tipos_fichas WHERE id_tipo='1')
```

[image]

As you can see, it only brings me the first result... as if I could only read the first process before the comma (the 3 of: 3,1,5,7,4,6,8)

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve it?

Comment: Please share sample data from tipos_fichas table. are datatypes same in both tables ?

Comment: You should use join instead of sub query, `SELECT P.* FROM 
procesos p
inner join tipos_fichas t on p.id_proceso = t.procesos
WHERE p.estatus=1 AND id_tipo='1'`

Comment: @PankajSanwal yes, it is an alternate solution. But the point is why subquery is not working.

Comment: Works for me. Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8493cb1ea6bc14e0896b57b54c020633)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL converts the string value `'3,1,5,7,4,6,8'` to the integer value `3` discarding the rest of the string. That's why the rest of the values are not found. This is a silent feature of MySQL that I personally dislike.

You can use the `LIKE` operator to find the matches you want, as in:

```
select p.* 
from procesos p
join tipos_fichas t on concat(',', t.procesos, ',') 
  like concat('%,', p.id_proceso, ',%')
where p.estatus = 1
```

Comment: But @Angel Sergio Ramírez is not passing the IDs  as string. It's passed either as comma separated vales or as sub query.

Comment: @PankajSanwal It seems the query `SELECT procesos FROM tipos_fichas WHERE id_tipo='1'` returns a single string with numbers and commas.